# Пропадает курсор в Memo (Delphi Rio)

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-10.3-rio

Проект Multi-Device Application (FireMonkey, не VCL). Target Win32.

На форме находится Memo и кнопка. По нажатию на кнопку берется текст из Memo, обрабатывается и выводится обратно. После этого текстовый курсор в Memo становится невидимым.

Как сделать, чтобы курсор не пропадал?

Минимальный воспроизводимый пример:

pas

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Memo1.Lines.Text := Memo1.Lines.Text;
end;
```

fmx

```
  object Memo1: TMemo
    Touch.InteractiveGestures = [Pan, LongTap, DoubleTap]
    DataDetectorTypes = []
    Align = Bottom
    ControlType = Platform
    Position.Y = 40.000000000000000000
    Size.Width = 640.000000000000000000
    Size.Height = 440.000000000000000000
    Size.PlatformDefault = False
    TabOrder = 0
    Viewport.Width = 636.000000000000000000
    Viewport.Height = 436.000000000000000000
  end
```

**UPD**

Если форма теряет фокус, а потом получает обратно, то курсор возвращается до следующего программного изменения свойства `Lines`.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте использовать свойство [TMemo.CaretPosition](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Rio/en/FMX.Memo.TCustomMemo.CaretPosition), чтобы установить курсор в нужную вам позицию (задав номер строки и номер символа).

Кроме того, чтобы курсор был видимым, компонент `Memo` должен быть в фокусе.

Comment: Не помогло. Судя по тому как Memo реагирует на нажатие кнопок клавиатуры и клики мышью - курсор есть, перемещается, но просто не отображается.

Comment: `Memo.Caret.Visible := True;` (как вариант - сначала False, потом True)?... И, кстати, Memo.Lines.Clear в коде выше - лишнее, т.к. назначение .Text заменяет весь текст.

Comment: Фокус с `Memo.Caret.Visible` тоже не прошел. Насчет `Clear` - согласен. Он остался из оригинального проекта, где запись была по средствам множества вызов `Add`. Поправил в вопросе.